# HTTP post Doesn't Work in my android app

Tags: android, android-activity

```
String HttpPost(String aURL) throws Exception
    {
        URL url = new URL(aURL);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String response="";
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            response+=inputLine;    

      //  Log.i(TAG, response);
        if(in!=null)
         in.close();
        return response;
   }


public void userpost(View v){

        txtUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserName);
        txtUserphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUserphone);
        txtUserphone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsermail);

        String Username = txtUsername.getText().toString();
        String Userphone = txtUserphone.getText().toString();
        String Usermail = txtUserphone.getText().toString();

        //action=staffadd&&sname=test1&&mobile=78545656566&&email=abr@abr.com&&imei=78945641235645
        String conString = "";
        conString = "action=staffadd";
        conString = url + "?" + conString +"&&sname=" +Username +"&&mobile=" +Userphone +"&&email=" + Usermail +"&&imei="+iIMEI;

        try {
            String response =HttpPost(conString);

            Log.i("REQUEST", conString);
            Log.i("Response", response);

            if (response.startsWith("Y")){

                return;
            }

            else if(response.startsWith("N"))
                return;

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }   

    }
```

If I click Submit button I got

> 02-13 00:13:02.103: I/Choreographer(553): Skipped 53 frames!  The
>   application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

I develop this app in android 4.4

Comment: Use a library like [`retrofit`](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) or [`volley`](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or u can use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for network call

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are using web service in the UI or main thread so you need to use AsyncTask for the web services.
See this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). Which give the idea how to use AsyncTask.
This is most common error

That link mention you everything. I just add code only here.

Step 1:
First you need to call the Asynctask like this

```
new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);
```

Step 2:
Implement your Async class

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Note: There is three methods `onPreExecute()`, `doInBackground()`, and `onPostExecute()`. Do your download works under `doInBackground()` method.

It is just sample code. Try your own.